# What part of speech is можно here?

Tags: грамматика

> Можно я попью чая?

What part of speech here is "можно"? Also, if possible, can you parse this sentence, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comprehensive edition Русская грамматика by the Russian Academy of Sciences (Наука, 1980)
http://lukashevichus.info/knigi/russk_gramm_sl_shvedova_1.pdf

says (p. 703):

> **Предикативы** — это слова с модальными значениями долженствования,
>   необходимости, возможности. Это — *самостоятельные слова*, не
>   соотносительные с *качественными* наречиями и краткими
>   прилагательными; например, *должно, **можно**, надо, нельзя, нужно,
>   устар. надобно*. По своим синтаксическим функциям эти слова совпадают с
>   предикативами в системе *существительных* [лень, недосуг]...

So, it's different from *adverb*. Unlikely there's an exact English term for предикатив in its defined meaning; here's a page using the term *predicative adverb*, however along with the words like надо, defined above, typical adverbs (like холодно) are included which are out of that definition.
http://russianlearn.com/grammar/category/predicative_adverbs

Another version of literally parsing the sentence (as opposed to proper translation with 'May I...'), in an attempt to replace *можно* with something as impersonal: *Is it OK if* I have some tea?

Comment: Искон. Бывшая форма ср. р. ед. ч. прил. можьнъ, суф. производного от мога «сила» (ср. подмога).

Answer (score 6):

"Можно" is наречие, i.e. adverb.

"Можно я попью чая?" may be translated as "Let me have some tea." or "May I have some tea?"

"Можно" is derived from "мочь" (to be able to), "могу" (I am able to, I can) and generally stands for posessing some permission, or ability, or affordance.

Answer (score 6):

Существует несколько вариантов названия для слов `можно` и `нельзя` как частей речи.
Например:

- наречия состояния,
- предикативные наречия,
- наречия в роли сказуемого.

В данном случае, я считаю наиболее подходящим вариантом *наречие в роли сказуемого*.
Таким образом, исходное предложение может быть разобрано как:

> я - подлежащее
>
> можно попью - сказуемое
>
> чай - дополнение

---

In English my answer is much shorter.
This is an *adverb as predicate*. In this sentence it is a part of complex predicate `можно попью`.

Comment: Really? If "можно попью" is сказуемое, then this sentence might be as well "я можно попью чая". And after completing this action you would say "я можно попил чая".
I would say the original sentence has a mistake - missing comma. It should be "Можно, я попью чая?", and I would translate it as "**Is it ok**, (if) I will have/drink some tea?".

Comment: @Mike Has: I'm upvoting your comment, only it needs just a teensy expansion: the original phrase **may** mean either **asking** for some tea, or asking for sort of permission to **drink** some tea (e.g., brought in a thermos).